# Can a ITS4100S-SJ-N High side power switch be used to switch AC/DC load

Tags: fet, plc

I have seen a PLC which uses the ITS4100S-SJ-N component to switch (just on/off) a 24V DC, 2A max. load.

I was asking if those components can also be used to switch 24V AC?

**Datasheet:**
https://www.infineon.com/cms/de/product/power/smart-low-side-and-high-side-switches/industrial-high-side-switch/ITS4100S-SJ-N/productType.html?productType=db3a30443a06def4013a2bc7fc9e28bd

Comment: Mind the body diode

Answer (score 1):

[image]

*Figure 1. The datasheet shows the internal structure. Note the diode is part of the MOSFET structure.*

It should be clear from the image in Figure 1 that, at best, the MOSFET would conduct on one half-cycle all the time.

The device is not suitable for AC switching.

If there was only one ITS chip and the AC supply is fully isolated from the PLC it might be possible to put this chip inside a bridge rectifier to control the AC load. In most PLC implementations the outputs share a group common so this would get complicated fairly quickly.

[image]

*Figure 2. A typical plug-in SSR.*

Normal practice is to use an SSR (solid-state relay). Most PLCs offer SSR output modules. If there is only one AC output required an external SSR is the best choice.

Answer (score 0):

No, because this power switch's actual switching element is a MOSFET. MOSFETS can only block voltage in one direction (which is what [PlasmaHH](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/39687/plasmahh) meant with his comment).

For switching AC you may use a relay or a SSR.